# How to reduce space between letters while keeping rotation data

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm modifying an older blender animation I did. I'm trying to decrease the space between letters in the word "Attack", to make it more accurate to the logo I'm recreating. The animation I'm trying to do has the logo spinning.
[image]

I tried to separate all the letters into their own object, and I was able to move the letters, but now they're rotating oddly. The letters get off center or something.

[image]

Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: pls provide blend file, because we have no idea how you did the letters (curve/mesh/text/GN...) or how you rotated them. thx. And it should be clear that the solution depends on how you did it.

Comment: [Here you go.](https://mega.nz/file/HxdnjJYI#1HWzG8l-3j6uAMFFsX15gnmRZfgY2LlSlxCWzws1JNU)

Answer (score 2):

While a text object is still a text object, you can change character spacing in properties/data/spacing:

[image]

If you have already converted to a mesh object, you will need to move the individual shapes.  This could be done without moving any objects, by instead moving the letters in edit mode:

[image]

Or, you could separate and move them in object mode, but you'd have to be a little careful.

When you separate something into multiple objects, they each inherit the origin-- the rotation point-- from what they were separated from. After you move these objects, they will rotate about this origin, wherever it is:

[image]

Notice the yellow dot and the red dot.  Those are the origins of "Tex" and "t" respectively, and that is the point that those objects will rotate about when I rotate them.

If I have a group of objects that all need to move as one, the general technique is to not manipulate them individually, but instead to parent them to something:

[image]

By parenting both objects to an empty, I can rotate the empty, and the other objects inherit that rotation about the location of the empty.  So I can easily make everything move as one, regardless of the origins of the individual children.

Comment: Moving in edit mode did the trick! Rotation looks good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

with this node setup:

[image]

you can change the distance + the x offset of your "attack":

[image]

Hope it helps! Good luck!